# Is there a way to identify the device data is being received from? (python)

Tags: python, serial-port

## Summary

I have an MT4000 device connected to my computer using the serial port **ttyS0**. This is broadcasting data which is being received and read by a udp listener written in Python. I am also sending data manually through the terminal using a bash script I wrote.

## The Goal

Is it possible to identify the device being used? The aim is for a web-page to allow the user to select which device they wish to see the data being sent. I would rather achieve this by directly identifying the device rather than saying anything from **ttyS0**, in case a different device is plugged in on that port.

## The Answer

Is this possible, and if so, how? Everything I have found so far, is on identifying through a specific port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which specific device do you have? You may know this, but serial connections don't have any device identification built into the protocol.

I did find a technical manual for the [MT4000 series](http://www.jvl.dk/files/_2011clean/filliste/accessories/user%20manuals/ev5000%20user%20manual-en.pdf%23page333) that states that these devices are running an embedded RTOS, but doesn't mention any specifics. If they support ssh, I wonder if you could bring up a terminal and use an OS command to grab an identifier.